# jsgrid jquery insert a table row above or below

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Am using **jsgrid** For rendering the table. I want to add/insert a row below or above from the current row. Currently, it's appending at the last row of the table.

Please refer the URL for reference 
URL1 (jsgrid) - http://js-grid.com/demos/
I have configured with the given documentation in js-grid.

Below URL has the actual requirement which I actually need. But I want to implement in Jsgrid
URL2 (jQuery-Dynamic-Data-Grid-Plugin-appendGrid)  -- http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Dynamic-Data-Grid-Plugin-appendGrid/

Can anyone help me on this,

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: For ex: if i click add symbol in current row, then a new row (<tr><td>Some value</td></tr>) should Add below or above the current table row.